# SQL Server transactional replication distributor

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

If I have a SQL Server 2012, with two databases, both publishers, replicating to a bunch of subscribers.

- Can each database go through a different distributor?
- Is the publisher the server or the database?

I understood it to be a publisher can only go to one distributor

- Is that each db or the whole server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Distributor is the **server** that contains the distribution database.

**Configure Distribution** at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151860.aspx says:

> By default, the Distributor is the same server as the Publisher (a
>   local Distributor), but it can also be a separate server from the
>   Publisher (a remote Distributor).

SQL Server can support a single Distributor on the local server.  If you are trying to reduce the load on the main server you can instead create the Distributor on a remote server.

If the load is heavy, an additional step that would help manage the distribution is to create a distribution database for each database that is being published.  This could reduce the contention within each database that might be present in a single distribution database.

Both a local server and a remote server can support multiple distribution databases.

David Poole's article from 2010, **Scaling Out the Distribution Database**. may provide you more insight.  It can be found here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Replication/69663/

Both articles are helpful and I have not detailed every step in the setup.